# Python Error: list index out of range

Tags: python, list

I keep getting the error list index out of range. I'm  not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My code:

```
from scanner import *

def small(array):
    smallest=array[0]
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if (array[i]<smallest):
            smallest=array[i]
    return smallest

def main():
    s=Scanner("data.txt")
    array=[]
    i=s.readint()
    while i!="":
        array.append(i)
        i=s.readint()
    s.close()
    print("The smallest is", small(array))

main()
```

The traceback I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "file.py", line 20, in main
    print("The smallest is", small(array))
  File "file.py", line 5, in small
    smallest=array[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you show us the full traceback please?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full traceback.

Comment: You're probably passing an empty array to the `small()` function.. consider adding error handling for that!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "file.py", line 20, in main
    print("The smallest is", small(array))
  File "file.py", line 5, in small
    smallest=array[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user3022573: Next time, [edit] your question to add the traceback. I've added it in for you.

Answer (score 5):

`array` is *empty*. There is no `array[0]` when a list is empty.

You could test for this edgecase, perhaps:

```
def small(array):
    if not array:
        return None
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the first call to `.readint()` returns `""`, then your array still is `[]` after the `while` loop, and therefore `array[0]` causes an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 1):

Is likely that the array you are passing is empty. For instance, if there's an empty line or empty data in the input file.